# How to use Nested static templated structs in c++17

Tags: c++, templates, struct, static, constants

What I am trying to achieve is to use a struct as a template parameter for another struct, without instantiation, so that it all happens at compile time. For example:

```cpp
template<int v>
struct Container {
    static const int value = v;
};

template<Container a, Container b>
struct BiggerContainer {
    static const int value = a.v > b.v ? a.v : b.v;
};

int main() {
std::cout << BiggerContainer<Container<42>, Container<42>>::value << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

The error I get with this code is the following:

```
./code.cpp: In function 'int main()':
./code.cpp:44:61: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<Container<...auto...> a, Container<...auto...> b> struct BiggerContainer'
   44 |     std::cout << BiggerContainer<Container<42>, Container<42>>::value << std::endl;
      |                                                             ^~
./code.cpp:44:61: note:   expected a constant of type 'Container<...auto...>', got 'Container<42>'
./code.cpp:44:61: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<Container<...auto...> a, Container<...auto...> b> struct BiggerContainer'
./code.cpp:44:61: note:   expected a constant of type 'Container<...auto...>', got 'Container<42>'
```

What am I getting wrong here? What exactly does this error mean what could I change to get at what I'm trying?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might have:

```
template <int v>
struct Container {
    static const int value = v;
};
// template <int v> using Container = std::integral_constant<int, v>;

template <typename lhs, typename rhs>
struct Max
{
    static const int value = lhs::value > rhs::value ? lhs::value : rhs::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Max<Container<42>, Container<42>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you cannot use a class or struct as a non-type template parameter.  Non-type parameters have to be ints, pointers, enums, or references.  This changes in C++20.

Specifically, the following declaration parameterizes `BiggerContainer` on **values** of structs, which is not possible.

```
template<Container a, Container b>
struct BiggerContainer
```

There are a few other problems with the code, but this is the main issue which will cause you to have to redesign things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your template arguments for `BiggerContainer`, you need to specify the template arguments for `Container` (`template<Container, Container>` doesn't have template arguments for `Container`).

One alternative is to use a template function, like this:

```
template<int v1, int v2>
int BiggerContainer(Container<v1> a, Container<v2> b)
{
    return a.value > b.value ? a.value : b.value;
}
```

Then calling it like:

```
BiggerContainer(Container<42>(), Container<42>()); // No need to add '::value'
```

NOTE: Must call constructer, `Container<val>()` not just a type `Container<val>`. (Because we're passing a value, not a type)

The problem with that solution is that it returns an int (value type), not a `Container`, but it may be okay for some uses.